# Addon Collections/Groups

Tags: customization

I am wondering if there is a way to have a specific selection of addons available when working through scene creation. Is there a way to dynamically load and unload a collection of addons? I would like to change the available addons based on the design task, layout, modeling, shading, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter addons for each workspace. In the viewport sidebar > Tool tab > Workspace panel > Filter Addon:

[image: filter addon]